# how to transfer value one page to another use javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a comment page, When someone click on the image.

I'm getting all the images from database and added `onclick` event listener to open the comment page.

i also want to transfer image id (id of clicked img ) which is 'IDpic' in database as value for comment page. below is the code Snippet.

```js
<?php
error_reporting (0);
$cat;
include 'dbcon.php';
$cat=$_SESSION["cat"];
$sql = "SELECT img FROM img WHERE cat LIKE '$cat'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($cat!=""){
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo '<a href="cmnt.php?id='".$row["IDpic"]."'"><img src ="'.$row["img"].'"'.'alt="pic" height="200px" width="250px" align = left onclick="clickedButton()" /></a>';
    }
} else {
    echo "no  pic  upload ";
}

}


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  function clickedButton() {
    window.location = 'cmnt.php';
  }
</script>
```

#### I want the solution without jQuery !

Comment: Wow. From when the code snippet started executing PHP? Or did PHP was added to HTML?

Comment: Php was added to html

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just give:

```
<a href="cmnt.php?id=12">
```

No JavaScript also!

Comment: but how pass image id as it is in loop it always get overwrite by last image id

Comment: echo '<a href="cmnt.php?id="'.$row["IDpic"].'"  method="post" ><img src ="'.$row["img"].'"'.'alt="pic" height="200px" width="250px" align = left onclick="clickedButton()" /></a>'; i try this but id has not pass

Comment: @NafizAlIfat Show the contents of `cmnt.php`?

Comment: <?php
$idpic=0;
echo $idpic=$_POST["id"];
?>

Comment: @NafizAlIfat Change it to `<?php $idpic=0; echo $idpic=$_GET["id"]; ?>`

Comment: cmnt.php page show  nothing and link is "/test/cmnt.php?id=" is my syntax is correct   echo '<a href="cmnt.php?id="'.$row["IDpic"].'" method="post" ><img src ="'.$row["img"].'"'.'alt="pic" height="200px" width="250px" align = left onclick="clickedButton()" /></a>';

Comment: @NafizAlIfat There's no `method="POST"`

Answer (score 1):

### To do

1. Remove your `onClick` Event.
2. Remove JS Code (`clickedButton` Function).

### Why should you remove it?

Your case doesn't require a JS method. Your image is enclosed by an Anchor tag that has your link. That will take care of your need.

Try the code below.

```
<?php
echo '<a href="cmnt.php?id='".$row["IDpic"]."'"><img src ="'.$row["img"].'"'.'alt="pic" height="200px" width="250px" align = left /></a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your page in a form and set and store the link in `hidden input type` and retrieve it  using `GET` , `POST` methods

You can use window variables if you want if  page does not reload.

Use  `window.location = '/your_page?data=' + name;`